# URL Scheme to open Safari from Facebook post

Tags: facebook, browser, safari, microphone

We are working on a website that requires users to allow microphone permission to interact with our web content.

However, when we open the website link from a Facebook post, it will always use Facebook-In-App-Browser.

And Facebook Browser doesn't have access to microphone/video permission.
So we're checking if there is a way to open the link in Safari browser from a Facebook post.

Here are some approaches that we tried:

1. Use Safari Scheme (safari-https://, safari://)
2. Use FTP to open Safari successfully but we can't run the Javascript with this protocol to redirect users to our main website.
3. And some others Stack Overflow suggestion:

[Is there a way to redirect users from facebook browser (onClick) enforcing the URL to open in chrome or any other browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55783157/is-there-a-way-to-redirect-users-from-facebook-browser-onclick-enforcing-the-u)

[Is there any way to force a link to open in Chrome from Facebook's in-app browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868048/is-there-any-way-to-force-a-link-to-open-in-chrome-from-facebooks-in-app-browse?rq=1)

But so far there is no luck.